# Force node-qrcode to put data into PNG files before the end of a script

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I'm trying to write a script that create several QR code PNG files and then does something with the the newly created files.
I'm using `node-qrcode` but it doesn't flash the data into the files before the end of the script. 
Here is the relevant part of the script:

```
const QRCode = require('qrcode')

const myFunc = async () => {
  return new Promise( (res, rej) => {
    QRCode.toFile(
      'foo.png',
      [{ data: [253,254,255], mode: 'byte' }],
      () => {
        res(true);
        console.log('callback')
      }
    )
  });
}

(async () => {
  await myFunc()
})()
console.log('almost done');
```

Comment: You need to put the `console.log` inside that `async` function, after the `await` - otherwise it won't wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the output will be the following and it is expected as NodeJS is still asynchronous even with `async`/`await`.

```
almost done
callback
```

NodeJS reaches `console.log('almost done');` first when processing your script, while `QRCode.toFile()` is working to resolve your promise and output `console.log('callback')`. Processing of QR code takes some time and it will be finished some time later, but `almost done` output is being reached first.

Also your outputs are executed in different contexts, so it is not expected to be executed one-by-one.

## UPD:

To execute sync and async operations in sequence you can do the following.

```js
(async () => {
  console.log('Operation before `myfunc`');
  await myFunc();
  console.log('Operation after `myfunc`');
  await smthElse();
  console.log('End Of Script');
})()
```

In this case you should **wrap** all your **initial scope into async function** and **invoke it in-place** like described above (*and in question*) with `(async () => { ... })()`. And your main scope will contain only this single function which is being invoked right away.

---

As stated in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> The `async` function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an `AsyncFunction` object. **An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result**. But the syntax and structure of your code using `async` functions is much more like using standard synchronous functions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question is how can i make sure the `QrCode.toFile` context is done **before** moving to the next part of the script?

Comment: @ShaiEfrati, updated my answer. Check if it explains.

Comment: i didn't need the "self invoking function" part, but your general solution made it clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: @ShaiEfrati, glad it helped!